# How to close power menu on android 12

Tags: android, dialog, system

everyone.
I am facing a difficult problem. I am building a small app related to security with java.
I want to close power menu when it appears.

Old android versions support `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS))`. But on new version, it throws Exception.
I did a lot search, read almost all previous articles here but not found the solution.
so I use AccessibilityService.performGlobalAction(ACTION_GLOBAL_BACK).. It works well on emulator. But not on some real devices.
Or any other way?
I want anybody to please help me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi. Could you please provide more detail, such as what is the power menu? For instance insert a screenshot of such power menu.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Power menu is one that you can show when power button is held. The real device that I used is oneplus 8 with android 13. What I want to do is requiring a password when the device is about to power off. I used timer to detect power menu and it's not so good. Please let me know the right way.